# Comparing two different Excel sheets in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets.  Sheet 1 has roughly ***2400 rows*** (and will continue to grow) and sheet 2 has roughly ***4400 rows*** (and will also continue to grow.  Sheet 1 has one column and sheet 2 has 2 columns (but I only care about the first column).  I need to compare sheet 1 and sheet 2 and be able to see what sheet 1 values are NOT in sheet 2. Ideally, this data would then populate a new sheet 3.

I have searched through many sites and many pages here with stackflow, but because I am so new at this, I'm not sure if I have come across what I need or not.  Everything I have tried is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have a look a  VLOOKUP https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function and see if that scratches your itch. Or MATCH https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Comment: Thanks - I think the first one will work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the already mentioned `vlookup` or `match` alternatives you may copy the values from Sheet1 to a new worksheet and add a column "source" where you enter "Sheet1". The same you do with the values from sheet 2. And then you create a pivot table to see immediately which values are on which sheet:

[image]