# Comparing two excel sheets and returns the values that are different in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a Project which requires me to compare two excel sheets and need to highlight the differences and also return the unique values.I was able to get it to be work till here but i would need help in copying these returned values in a different sheet but under the same headers meaning the values returned must have their corresponding headers under them.  I have written the code till here need further assistance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare_Two_Excel_Sheets_Highlight_Differences()
    'Define Fields
    Dim iRow As Double, iCol As Double, oRow As Double
    Dim iRow_Max As Double, iCol_Max As Double
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim shOut As Worksheet
    
    'Sheets to be compared
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Set shOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    
    'Max Rows
    iRow_Max = sh1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iCol_Max = sh1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    'Read Data From Each Sheets of Both Excel Files & Compare Data
    For iRow = 1 To iRow_Max
    For iCol = 1 To iCol_Max
        sh1.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = xlNone
        sh2.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = xlNone
        
        'Compare Data From Excel Sheets & Highlight the Mismatches
        If sh1.Cells(iRow, iCol) <> sh2.Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
           sh1.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           sh2.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           
           'Write Differences to Output sheet
           oRow = oRow + 1
           shOut.Cells(oRow, 1) = sh1.Cells(iRow, iCol)
           shOut.Cells(oRow, 2) = sh2.Cells(iRow, iCol)
        End If
    Next iCol
    Next iRow
    
    'Process Completed
    MsgBox "Task Completed"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect exercise for a `Math()`- and/or `VLookup()`-based conditional formatting. So why VBA?

Comment: So did you do a search on here before posting? Find anything? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54814418/4961700

Comment: I am using VBA because i will have to run it multiple times..!! And every time I will not be able to use V-lookup as it would make things tedious